# Debugging SMTP connection

Tags: smtp, go

I use go's `net/smtp` to send emails, and it works fine for some emails but not for others. I get an `554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients` but I am pretty sure I give the correct mail address.

(The ultimate goal is to make the `net/smtp` work for all mail recipients. So answers on that are welcome as well)

How can I debug what's going on in the background? What commands are sent to and from the SMTP server? I'd like to replay the commands from the command line (telnet) to get find out more about the error.

This is the code I use ([from the go-wiki](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SendingMail)):

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "log"
        "net/smtp"
)

func main() {
        // Connect to the remote SMTP server.
        c, err := smtp.Dial("mail.example.com:25")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // Set the sender and recipient.
        c.Mail("sender@example.org")
        c.Rcpt("recipient@example.net")
        // Send the email body.
        wc, err := c.Data()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer wc.Close()
        buf := bytes.NewBufferString("This is the email body.")
        if _, err = buf.WriteTo(wc); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

I know this is a very vague question, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with recipients that you are able to publish so we can reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: @nemo I have done some further debugging and it looks as if the other host requires a non-localhost `EHLO` command. So a `client.Hello(myhost)` helped. Should I self-answer the question or delete it altogether?

Comment: Definitely self-answer! This is valuable information for anyone with the same person.

Comment: Thanks, @nemo. I really appreciate your (and others) help and patience and not to be downvoted to -∞.

Answer (score 4):

It looks (after some debugging), that the servers who rejected the valid email addresses require a `EHLO` command with a proper hostname, not just `localhost` which is the default as [documented](http://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Client.Hello)

So when I insert a line in the beginning like this

```
c.Hello("example.com") // use real server name here
```

everything works fine. **BUT:** (note to myself): never run code without proper error checking. It helped me to check the error on all the commands such as

```
err = c.Hello("example.com")
...
err = c.Mail("sender@example.org")
...
err = c.Rcpt("recipient@example.net")
...
```

I am not sure anymore which error message gave me the hint to use a proper hostname, but it was something like:

```
550 5.7.1 <localhost>: Helo command rejected: Don't use hostname localhost
```